# I have a column in which i have varchar data and i want to convert that data into TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

My data, which I have in varchar (datatype), is in this form:

```
14-12-2021 Tuesday 14:30:00
22-11-2021 Monday 13:00:00
05-10-2021 Tuesday 11:45:00
24-09-2021 Friday 10:15:00
11-08-2021 Wednesday 12:15:00
01-07-2021 Thursday 00:45:00
17-06-2021 Thursday 03:30:00
21-05-2021 Friday 02:15:00
04-04-2021 Sunday 02:45:00
```

And I would like this data to convert in `TIMESTAMP`.

My Output Should be:

```
14-12-2021  14:30:00
22-11-2021  13:00:00
05-10-2021  11:45:00
24-09-2021  10:15:00
11-08-2021  12:15:00
01-07-2021  00:45:00
17-06-2021  03:30:00
21-05-2021  02:15:00
04-04-2021  02:45:00
```

I have tried many things but nothing is helping me out. Can someone please help me? I do not want to alter the data manually. I would like to update my data with SQL query.

Comment: The data which is showing is in tabular form

Comment: Try using STR_TO_DATE() with the proper mask . See DATE_FORMAT for available specifiers https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to *convert* your data to a bona fide timestamp, you may use `STR_TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 1), ' ',
                          SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1)),
                   '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS ts_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Assuming you just want to *view* your data this way, you may use:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 1), ' ',
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1)) AS ts_out
FROM yourTable;
```

To update your table, first create a new timestamp column `ts_out` then populate it using:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET ts_out = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 1), ' ',
                                SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1)),
                         '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: i dont want to just view i want to update my output into actual table also

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 1), ' ',
                          SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1)),
                   '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS ts_out
FROM yourTable; 

while running this query output showing null values

Comment: I think your data has some problem.  [Check here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe6585cc410f0164ca45d394f5953ab1) to see my first query working against some of your data as shown.

Comment: i have checked your query it was running fine i got my output but when i run your update query , and to notify you i have first create timestamp datatype column in my existing table but i got error showing: Error code 1411

Comment: The problem is either your data (some of which may be corrupt), or your DDL, but I don't think there is anything wrong with my answer.

Comment: hey i want output in dd/mm/yyyy format and data is coming into yyyy/mm/dd format

Comment: No, the output from my first answer matches the format you want.  Dates don't have any internal format.  If you want to _view_ your dates this way, then you'll have to use `DATE_FORMAT()`.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe6585cc410f0164ca45d394f5953ab1 you can check here your output is coming in yyyy/mm/dd form

Comment: Either use my second query, or else call `DATE_FORMAT` on the bona fide timestamp using whatever format mask you really want here.  Dates have no internal format in MySQL.